# Which institution regulates rocket launches of all countries?

Tags: launch, orbit, regulatory

Which institution regulates the rocket launches of all countries? Meaning, suppose a country wants to launch a rocket, where do they have to report it before the actual launch and how far ahead? Secondary question, who regulates whether a country can put a satellite in certain orbit or not?